# How to remove google drive folder from Computer

Tags: linux-mint, partition, unmounting, delete, google-drive

Is there a way to definitely delete the `google drive` folder appeared in the *Computer* desktop folder in Linux Mint 19.2?
It seems it is treated from the os like a mounted partition, but unmounting it did not work. 
Of course, also trying to simply move the folder to the trash didn't have any effect as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Mint 20.3 with Cinnamon, and the solution just occurred to me and worked for me.

If you have a Gmail account setup for email and/or calendar:

1. Go to the application menu on Cinnamon.
2. Type in “online accounts”.
3. Click Google.
4. Make sure that documents, photos, and files are turned off (along with whatever else you may want to turn off such as either printers or contacts).

Once I completed that process, my Google drive disappeared from my browser.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no defautl installation, are you sure that you do not install the 'google-drive-ocamlfuse' ?  :

[https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse-linux](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/google-drive-ocamlfuse/)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure not using **google-drive-ocamlfuse**

Comment: The folder is still there after reboot?

Comment: I have just upgraded to Mint 19.3 and the folder is still there

Comment: What are the properties of this folder ?Did you try to delete with sudo command  ?

Comment: No because I can't find the folder within the terminal. As far as I know, the **Computer** folder is just an abstraction used in the desktop env, I can't find it in the filesystem (this is right the main point of my problem)

Comment: I suggest to [code]
sudo apt-get remove caja  && sudo apt-get install caja[code]
but i cannot guarantee that it will not broke something, the file navigator is closely linked with the IF.

Comment: 'caja' is not installed

Comment: Strange, 'caja' is the Mint's default file browser.  Wich did you use ?

Comment: I'm using Nemo, which I think now is the default one in Mint

Comment: OK I use MATE, Caja is default, and Nemo for Cinnamon. [code] sudo apt-get remove nemo && sudo apt-get install nemo [code]

Comment: Done, and it didn't work. It' s a really strange and annoying problem

Comment: I have to admit that it is a first see problem  !